# Poner límites en un programa JAVA

Tags: java

Quisiera saber cómo ponerle que el número de intentos sea igual a 5.
Necesito hacer un programa que el usuario adivine un número random, en un máximo de 5 intentos.

```
do{
    intentos++;
    numero=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un número"));

    if(aleatorio<numero){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese un número mas bajo");

    }else if(aleatorio>numero){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese un número mas alto");

    }

}while(numero!=aleatorio);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Excelente, conseguiste adivinar el número en " + intentos + " intentos");

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He editado tu código, solo condicione diferente el **while** para que haga el recorrido solo 5 veces. Para cuando el usuario adivine coloqué un **break** lo cual rompe el ciclo.

```
        do {
            intentos++;
            numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese un número"));

            if (numero == aleatorio) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                        "Excelente, conseguiste adivinar el número en " + intentos + " intentos");
                break;
            }

            if (aleatorio < numero) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese un número mas bajo");

            } else if (aleatorio > numero) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese un número mas alto");

            }

        } while (intentos < 5);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`while ( (numero != aleatorio) && (intentos < 5 ) );` te podría servir.

Suponiendo que inicializas
`intentos = 0;`

Espero que te sea útil, saludos.